# Sort records by both time and weightage

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have an input set of log records which have the attributes, record, time and weightage.

I need an output where the first 5 records should be based on the time and the next 5 should be sorted based on weightage. No duplicates allowed.

Is there a datastructure in java, or any type of algorithms to solve these kind of issues.

Input

```
Record  Time        Weightage

R1      11:40:52    1 
R2      11:39:23    2
R3      11:39:21    2
R4      11:38:44    5
R5      11:37:00    3
R6      11:36:12    3
R7      11:35:12    1
R8      11:34:00    1
R9      11:33:04    5
R10     11:32:02    4
R11     11:31:44    3
R12     11:30:12    2
R13     11:29:02    5
R14     11:28:28    6
R15     11:27:18    4
R16     11:26:19    6
R17     11:25:12    7
R18     11:24:03    5
R19     11:23:03    4
R20     11:22:05    4
R21     11:21:06    6
R22     11:20:00    4
R23     11:19:00    9
```

Output

```
Record  Time        Weightage
R1      11:40:52    1
R2      11:39:23    2
R3      11:39:21    2
R4      11:38:44    5
R5      11:37:00    3
R23     11:19:00    9
R17     11:25:12    7
R14     11:28:28    6
R16     11:26:19    6
R21     11:21:06    6
R6      11:36:12    3
R7      11:35:12    1
R8      11:34:00    1
R9      11:33:04    5
R10     11:32:02    4
R13     11:29:02    5
R18     11:24:03    5
R15     11:27:18    4
R19     11:23:03    4
R20     11:22:05    4
R11     11:31:44    3
R12     11:30:12    2
R22     11:20:00    4
```

Comment: Sort by time, pick the 5 first. Sort by weight, pick the 5 first that haven't been picked already.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the list is sorted by `time`. 
Add another attribute to the list, `picked` (say) as boolean and set all to false initially.
If space is no issue, make a copy of data and sort it according to `weight` as well.

Now, pick 1st 5 from list1 (time sorted) and set their `picked` attr. to true. Now, start picking from list2, and check if the record that you are picking, if its `picked` value is false or not in list1. (If its `true`, don't pick this one). As you are done picking 5 from this list, continue from 6th item in list1 while cheking its `picked` attribute from list2. To check `picked` value, use `record_no` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method:

- Sort by `Time`
- Slice after the 5th element. Keep the first subarray.
- Sort the second subarray by `Weightage`
- Concatenate

If your dataset is really huge (but since it fits in RAM it can't be that huge), it might make sense to over optimize this.
Getting the max 5 elements from a list would run in `O(n)`, compared to the `O(n log(n))` of sorting the whole thing. Then, sorting 5 elements runs in constant time, so it can all be reduced to `O(n)`.